# Уведомления на уровне системы

Tags: c#, wpf, уведомления

Разрабатываю софт для компьютерных клубов.
В приложении есть кастомные уведомления (см. фото), которые должны появляться, даже когда пользователь в игре.
Очевидно, что сейчас они появляются на уровне приложения (окна).

Господа, буду рад услышать ваше мнение!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мнение что ничего не понятно но очень интересно. Где сам вопрос, собственно?

Comment: @Andrew, ну и что же тут может быть непонятно? Для непонятливых вопрос: как показать окно поверх игры? Ну и ещё как вообще показать окно? :(

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите просто показать окно поверх всех окон в системе. Можно сделать следующим образом:

Создаете новое окно со следующим стилем
Window.xaml

```xml
<Window
Topmost="True" 
Background="Любой" 
ResizeMode="NoResize"
ShowInTaskbar="False" 
WindowStyle="None" 
AllowTransparency="True">
Ваше окно с контролами
</Window>
```

И если, допустим, вы хотите показать это окно справа снизу, то вызывайте из конструктора данный метод:

```
private void UpdateWindowSize()
{
    Width = "Ширина окна";
    Height = "Высота окна";

    Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Right - Width;
    Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Bottom - Height;
}
```

Но это велосипед. Есть [HandyControl](https://github.com/HandyOrg/HandyControl) - библиотека компонентов для wpf и в ней есть как раз-таки такие окна. [Демо с контролами](https://github.com/HandyOrg/HandyControl/releases/download/v3.2.0/HandyControl-v3.2.0-Release.7z).

Comment: Подозреваю что поверх игры в полноэкранном режиме такое окно всё равно не появится...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ага, я в свое время сам с оверлеями для полноэкранок мучался, плюнул и написал плагин для Overwolf. Но это было давно. Сейчас бы смело копал в сторону DirectX и готовых решений.

Comment: @Qwertiy тестировал в этом году на .net5. Все работает.

Comment: @Lapish, а точно у игры в настройках выбран полноэкранный режим, а не оконный без рамки? Если в игре нажать и удерживать alt+tab, то игра сворачивается сама или оно появляется поверх неё?

Comment: @Qwertiy оконный был, а на счет второго не знаю(не себе делал).

Comment: На оконном режиме легче легкого оверлей сделать. А вот в полноэкранном - уже интереснее.

Comment: @Lapish, ну с оконным-то всё понятно, но вопрос вроде про полноэкранный. И как особый сюрприз можно докинуть полноэкранный с изменением разрешения экрана.